# Pom.xml gives me NPE

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

I have the POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CucumberNG</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberNG</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CucumberNG</name>
    <description>How to use Cucumber and TestNG</description>
    <build>
        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I inserted at the end the dependency for Selenium

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I got NPE.

See my attachment.
[image]

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

here is my log:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:566)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:60)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(ZipFile.java:524)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:499)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:480)
at  org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getJavaDocPathInArchive             (BuildPathManager.java:692)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getJavaDocUrl(BuildPathManager.java:677)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getJavaDocUrl(BuildPathManager.java:670)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.configureAttchedSourcesAndJavadoc(BuildPathManager.java:306)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:255)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:363)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:343)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.getClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:371)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.updateClasspath(BuildPathManager.java:191)
at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.BuildPathManager.mavenProjectChanged(BuildPathManager.java:180)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.notifyProjectChangeListeners(ProjectRegistryManager.java:783)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.applyMutableProjectRegistry(ProjectRegistryManager.java:930)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:300)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Can you consider to properly format the `pom.xml` please? Thanks

Comment: Eclipse has an error log. Have a look in it, and post the full stacktrace; it should be a little more helpful.

Comment: In Eclpse there is a Command Format. I used this for my pom file.

Comment: First try to build that project via plain Maven from command line via `mvn clean package`afterwards check what's happening in Eclipse...

Comment: have you tried to project > right click > maven >update project and then check force updates and click finish?

Comment: I tried and I received the same error message.

Comment: I resolved.I deleted jar file from repo. I close the project and then I reopen the project.